# The ID given by the Facebook Graph API is not the same as the Profile ID

Tags: api, facebook, graph

Example:

https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100005820853314 = profile id: 100005820853314

https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id = id: 162711601******

When users log in to my website with facebook, I want to get profile id from graph api.

Is there another way to view the facebook pages of people logged into my site with facebook?

Comment: You can't. The API returns an App scoped user ID. There is no way to get their real ID.

Comment: There is a link field you can use to get a link to their profile.